# multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How do i create from the following code ?

```
      var x = [12, 155, 177];
      var y = [120, 175, 255];
      var z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300];
      var value = [];



      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

          for (var index = x[i]; index < y[i]; index++) {

              value.push(z[index]);

          }

      }

      console.log(value);
```

this code generate a one dimensional array from 12 to 12 , 155 to 175 and 177 to 255 
RESULT : [13 ,.....,120 , 155 ,.......,175 , 177 ,.........,255]

what i want to do is create another array in this array to get 
[[13....120] , [155,.....,175] , [175,.....,255]] ;

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/SK2vJ/

THANKS

Comment: Are you the same person who asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534533/array-push-with-json/10535298#10535298) using a different account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 var x = [12, 155, 177];
 var y = [120, 175, 255];
 var z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300];
  var value = [];



  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

      var temp = []

      for (var index = x[i]; index < y[i]; index++) {

          temp.push(z[index]);

      }

      value.push(temp);

  }

  console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite following exactly what you want to do, but here's some info which should help.

JavaScript doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays. (In fact, JavaScript arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html).) But you can have an array which has arrays as element values. So:

```
var i, j, a, sub;

// Create the main array
a = [];

// This loop creates the outermost level
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    // Here we create the array to store in a[i]:
    sub = [];

    // This loop builds it up
    for (j = 0; j < 20; ++j) {
        sub[j] = "I'm the element at a[" + i + "][" + j + "]"; // Just a sample value
    }

    // Remember this sub-array
    a[i] = sub;
}
console.log("a[1][12] = " + a[1][12]); // "I'm the element at a[1][12]"
```

Key notes on the above:

1. You have to create each of the subordinate arrays in the loop
2. You don't have to pre-allocate or anything like that, you can extend an array just by assigning to an element. (`push` also works. It's a *teeny* bit slower, but that usually doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. I also used a for loop to generate the `z` array instead of writing it out manually.

```
var x = [12, 155, 177], y = [120, 175, 255], z = [], value = [];

// generate z, 1 to 300
for(var i = 1; i<=300; i++) {
    z.push(i);
}

for(var i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++) {
    var arr = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < y[i]; j++) {
        arr.push(z[j]);
    }

    value.push(arr);
}
```